# Getting a bool value from DataTable with linq

Tags: mysql, wpf, linq, datatable, boolean

I have to fill a DataGrid using a DataTable, and linq. The DataTable contains a MySql table (i am using linq to optimize the program in terms of network traffic), but when the linq tries to get the boolean values from the DataTAble i get an "InvalidCastException" exc. with "The 'OneWay' or 'TwoWay' binging can not work..." text. Is there any way to make it work? (sry for bad eng)

```
            string q = "Select * from `beszallitoi_megrendeles` "
                  + "where megrendelt='1' and beerkezett='0' "
                  + "order by megrendeles_datuma desc;";
            parancs = new MySqlCommand(q, Kapcsolat);
            Kapcsolat.Open();
            parancs.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(parancs);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("beszallitoi_megrendeles");
        mda.Fill(dt);
        mda.Update(dt);
...
        var results = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      select new
                      {
                          AZ = a.Field<int>("AZ"),
                          MEGRENDEL = a.Field<DateTime>("MEGRENDEL"),
                          KERTSZDATUM = a.Field<DateTime>("KERTSZDATUM"),
                          VEVO_CSOPORT = a.Field<string>("VEVO_CSOPORT"),
                          ROVIDVEVONEV = a.Field<string>("ROVIDVEVONEV"),
                          GYARTO = a.Field<string>("GYARTO"),
                          MEGNEVEZES = a.Field<string>("MEGNEVEZES"),
                          DARAB = a.Field<int>("DARAB"),
                          MEGJEGYZES = a.Field<string>("MEGJEGYZES"),
                          RENDSZAM = a.Field<string>("RENDSZAM"),
                          BRENDSZAM = a.Field<string>("BRENDSZAM"),
                          ROGNEV = a.Field<string>("ROGNEV"),
                          BESZALLITO = a.Field<string>("BESZALLITO"),
                          MEGREND = a.Field<DateTime>("MEGREND"),
                          VARERK = a.Field<DateTime>("VARERK"),
                          CSKULD = a.Field<string>("CSKULD"),
                          MEGJEGY2 = a.Field<string>("MEGJEGY2"),
                          BMEGREND = a.Field<bool>("BMEGREND"),
                          BERKDAT = a.Field<DateTime>("BERKDAT"),
                          BEERK = a.Field<bool>("BEERK")
                      };
        DgUjMegrendeles.ItemsSource = results;
```

EDIT:
Here is the boolean column: ( i modified the mode from "TwoWay" to "OneWay" then "OneTime" but this way all the rows had true values)

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Width="45" Header="MREND." Binding="{Binding BMEGREND, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: What's the exact exception?

Comment: I think it's DBNull there, but surely we need exact exception

Comment: Additional information: The TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work for  „<>f__AnonymousType0`19[System.Int32,System.DateTime,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32]” type of read-only „BMEGREND” attribute.

Comment: Well, ok, set it to OneWay binding.

Comment: is BMEGREND a nullable column on DB?

Comment: @Dephott I'm guessing your `DataGrid` columns bind two way and you cannot do that with anonymous type, as per exception.

Comment: thanks it works but this way all checkbox have always true value :/ any other way to do it?

Comment: so it cant be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous type you're creating (`new { AZ = ... }`) has read only properties. You are trying to bind to something using a `TwoWay` binding mode. You will have to set the binding mode to `OneWay` or `OneTime`. You don't show your XAML, however.

Comment: i created an auto-property named "Lista" (select new Lista() {..}) and this way it works with "TwoWay" mode. thanks!